# can not unrar the files

Tags: linux, bash

The following is my machine, its VM

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Dec 6 19:48:22 GMT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I downloaded and untar the rar packages like following

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 cloudera     cloudera       4096 Dec 12  2009 rar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cloudera     cloudera     831871 Dec 12  2009 rarlinux-3.9.1.tar.gz
```

went to RAR folder

```
[cloudera@localhost rar]$ ls -ltr rar unrar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cloudera cloudera 205328 Dec 12  2009 unrar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cloudera cloudera 364580 Dec 12  2009 

[cloudera@localhost rar]$ ./unrar
bash: ./unrar: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory
```

but If I try with sudo , error suppress but no output

```
[cloudera@localhost rar]$ sudo ./unrar e /home/cloudera/Downloads/xyz.rar 
[cloudera@localhost rar]$ <<<Nothing happens>>>> 

[cloudera@localhost rar]$ ls /home/cloudera/Downloads/
xyz.rar ----<<< same one file remains the unrar does not work>>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ewww! Cloudera - My Pet hate! ;-)

Looks like you are missing a dependancy I did this with a Fedora box and got your error and resolved it with:

yum install glibc.i686

May need to adapt depending on your Linux Distro

HTH's Thanks //P

Comment: So I did sudo yum Install glibc.i686
                                                     
[cloudera@localhost rar]$ ./unrar
./unrar: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Ok install libstdc++ ;-) Silly Q did you install unrar with yum as well? should solve your deps for you

Comment: Used following 

wget http://www.rarlab.com/rar/rarlinux-3.9.1.tar.gz then

“tar -zxvf rarlinux-3.9.1.tar.gz”.

Comment: Try a:
    sudo yum install unrar
Package Managers are your Friends!

Comment: sudo yum install unrar
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.constant.com
 * epel: mirror.cogentco.com
 * extras: centos.mirror.constant.com
 * updates: mirrors.einstein.yu.edu
Setting up Install Process
No package unrar available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: My Bad - Assumed Fedora here - wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/unrar/unrar-4.0.7-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm && rpm -Uvh unrar-4.0.7-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm #Should do the trick